# Obtain file name from SetClipboardData hook

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll-injection

I used EasyHook to hook into the `SetClipboardData()` function.

```
HANDLE mySetClipBoardData (UINT uFormat, HANDLE hMem){
    return SetClipboardData(uFormat, hMem);
    //return NULL;
}
```

I can either pass the data to the original function or return NULL.

The goal is to prevent the user from copying specific files.

This DLL will be injected into `Explorer.exe` and will be called whenever a user tries to copy a file.

How to obtain the filename being copied?

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: `GetFinalPathFromHandle` require file handle. hMem - not a file handle

Comment: Yes i know. I tried that with NtOpenFile function which has a file handle.I forgot to remove GetFinalPathFromHandle from question.

Comment: you need call `GetClipboardFormatName` - may be you get `CFSTR_FILENAMEW` or `CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST`

Comment: *I tried that with NtOpenFile function* - but you need have file name for this first

Comment: @RbMm i used GetFinalPathFromHandle when i hooked into the NtOpenFile function from ntdll. GetClipboardFormatName outputs multiple values such as DataObject, ShellIdListArray, DataObjectAttributes, FileName, FileNameW.

Comment: @RbMm is there anyway to get filename or path from the handle?

Comment: of course exist. but i not understand your question - are this about clipboard data, are this about get file name by handle..

Comment: if you have `FileNameW` (same as `CFSTR_FILENAMEW`) - what else you want ?

Comment: @RbMm i want to get the filename before it goes to clipboard so i can prevent or allow it based on the file name.

Comment: so ask another question - i have file handle - how get file path by it. or something else. how here clipboard related ?

Comment: You realize the user can just copy the file in other ways?

Comment: @Anders yes the scope of the hook is to only prevent copy action using ctrl+c or copy from right click menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files can be copied/pasted using a number of different clipboard formats, and multiple formats can reside on the clipboard at the same time.

- CF_HDROP
- CFSTR_FILECONTENTS
- CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR
- CFSTR_FILENAME
- CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP
- CFSTR_MOUNTEDVOLUME
- CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST
- CFSTR_SHELLIDLISTOFFSET

Refer to [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard) for specific details about each format.  In particular, see [Formats for Transferring File System Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#formats-for-transferring-file-system-objects).

So, you would need something like this:

```
const UINT ui_CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST);
const UINT ui_CFSTR_FILENAMEA = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILENAMEA);
const UINT ui_CFSTR_FILENAMEW = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILENAMEW);
...

HANDLE WINAPI mySetClipBoardData (UINT uFormat, HANDLE hMem)
{
    if (!hMem) // DELAYED RENDERING! The real data will come later...
        return SetClipboardData(uFormat, hMem);

    if (uFormat == CF_HDROP)
    {
        LPDROPFILES pDF = (LPDROPFILES) GlobalLock(hMem);
        if (pDF->fWide)
        {
            LPWSTR pFiles = (LPWSTR) (((LPBYTE)pDF) + pDF->pFiles);
            while (*pFiles)
            {
                LPWSTR pFile = pFiles;
                if (pFile refers to the desired file)
                {
                    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                    SetLastError(...);
                    return NULL;

                    // alternatively, build up a new string to place on the clipboard that omits this file...
                }
                pFiles += (lstrlenW(pFile) + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LPSTR pFiles = (LPSTR) (((LPBYTE)pDF) + pDF->pFiles);
            while (*pFiles)
            {
                LPSTR pFile = pFiles;
                if (pFile refers to the desired file)
                {
                    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                    SetLastError(...);
                    return NULL;

                    // alternatively, build up a new string to place on the clipboard that omits this file...
                }
                pFiles += (lstrlenA(pFile) + 1);
            }
        }

        GlobalUnlock(hMem);

        /* alternatively:

        TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];
        UINT count = DragQueryFile((HDROP)hMem, (UINT)-1, NULL, 0);
        for (UINT i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            DragQueryFile((HDROP)hMem, i, szFile, MAX_PATH);
            if (szFile refers to the desired file)
            {
                SetLastError(...);
                return NULL;

                // alternatively, build up a new string to place on the clipboard that omits this file...
            }
        }
        */
    }
    else if (uFormat == ui_CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST)
    {
        #define HIDA_GetPIDLFolder(pida) (LPCITEMIDLIST)(((LPBYTE)pida)+(pida)->aoffset[0])
        #define HIDA_GetPIDLItem(pida, i) (LPCITEMIDLIST)(((LPBYTE)pida)+(pida)->aoffset[i+1])

        LPIDA pIDA = (LPIDA) GlobalLock(hMem);
        LPCITEMIDLIST pidlParent = HIDA_GetPIDLFolder(pIDA);

        for (UINT i = 0; i < pIDA->cidl; ++i)
        {
            LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFile = HIDA_GetPIDLItem(pIDA, i);

            if (pidlParent+pidlFile refers to the desired file)
            {
                GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                SetLastError(...);
                return NULL;

                // alternatively, build up a new array to place on the clipboard that omits this file...
            }
        }

        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    }
    else if (uFormat == ui_CFSTR_FILENAMEA)
    {
        LPSTR pFile = (LPSTR) GlobalLock(hMem);
        if (pFile refers to the desired file)
        {
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            SetLastError(...);
            return NULL;
        }
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    }
    else if (uFormat == ui_CFSTR_FILENAMEW)
    {
        LPWSTR pFile = (LPWSTR) GlobalLock(hMem);
        if (pFile refers to the desired file)
        {
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            SetLastError(...);
            return NULL;
        }
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    }
    else
    {
        // handle other shell formats as needed...
    }

    return SetClipboardData(uFormat, hMem);
}
```